Do we have evidence that explanations that contain a minimal number of entities are true?
Does our universe require all our explanations to be the most minimal?
For example, entropy indicates that everything in our universe tends to a minimum.
So all explanations should be as minimal as possible?
That is, ontological simplicity is the main criterion for choosing the best explanation? Should the best explanation be the most minimal?
Solipsism is the most minimal explanation because it contains only one entity (my mind), so it is ontologically the simplest explanation.
The existence of other minds is a more complicated explanation because it says that there are billions of people and all people have minds. This explanation contains many entities (billions of minds) and is ontologically much more complex.
So, if all our explanations must be the most minimal, then it turns out that solipsism is true?
Is there evidence that the most minimal explanations are true? Is entropy one of the arguments in favor of the most minimal explanations?

Does this answer your question? Limitations to Occam's razor

Simpler structures, for the most part, occur more frequently in nature than more complex structures. This is what Occam's razor / kolmogrov complexity are trying to generalize from, but at a higher level of abstraction

It is metaphysically impossible for evidence to support or contradict solipsism, because if one accepts solipsism, there is no such thing as evidence.

If solipsism is true, why are you asking question of imaginary people?

It is simpler that each person has their own mind than that one mind controls billions. It is simpler that each atom is affected directly by the atoms around it than that God controls stupendous numbers of atoms.

If Occam's razor says that we should choose the explanation that has the least number of entities, then solipsism wins. But the explanatory power of the existence of other minds is stronger than that of solipsism. Is explanatory power more important than number of entities?

Solomonoff's Theory of Inductive Inference

NO
to all questions.
(ontology is not about simplification, but realization)
